# Error al instalar rvm en Ubuntu

Tags: rvm

tengo el problema de que al querer instalar rvm en ubuntu 20, el error que me arroja es de retrieving gpg key timed out.
Según lo que he estado haciendo y tratando no logro encontrar una solución que me resuelva. Al parecer no se logra conectar al servidor para poder descargar el repositorio, necesito ayuda.

Comment: This is an english only site, and you're details are rather unclear.  Are you using Ubuntu Core 20, as there is no Ubuntu 20, and the releases using the *year* format (20) differ to those using the far more widely used *year.month* format (ie. 20 is not 20.04; different products).   You can download & install *snap* packages off-line, but no other store provides them (ie. you cannot add repositories to a Ubuntu Core 20 system).

Comment: @guiverc I had some concerns about translating posts using Google Translate, so I brought it up on Meta Ask Ubuntu, and the consensus [is that we should not use Google Translate](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19895/) to translate posts. Instead, they should be flagged as "Needs details or clarity"

Comment: Thank you @cocomac